# Why am I only receiving 50 messages with MessageManager.fetch()?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm in the process of debugging the `/purge` command for my Discord bot.

My intention is to fetch **the entirety of a text channel**, and delete **any** amount of messages, by calling the `TextChannel.bulkDelete` method multiple times, since that method has a limit of deleting **100 messages at a time**. This is my code:

```js
    async purgeDelete(
        channel: TextChannel,
        amount: number | undefined,
        target: GuildMember | undefined,
        keyword: string | undefined
    ): Promise<number> {
        // Most confused about this line: Am I doing the right thing?
        const messages = await channel.messages.fetch();
        
        const twoWeeksAgo = new Date();
        twoWeeksAgo.setDate(twoWeeksAgo.getDate() - 14);
        
        const purgelist = messages.filter(message => (
            (!target || message.author.id === target.id)
            && (!keyword || message.content.includes(keyword))
            && this.resultMessage?.id !== message.id
            && message.createdAt > twoWeeksAgo
        ));
        
        let purgeAmount: number;
        if (amount === undefined) {
            purgeAmount = purgelist.size;
        } else {
            console.log(purgelist.size, messages.size);
            purgeAmount = Math.min(amount, purgelist.size);
        }
        
        const slicedPurgelist = purgelist.first(purgeAmount);
        const partitionedPurgelist = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < slicedPurgelist.length; i += 100) {
            partitionedPurgelist.push(slicedPurgelist.slice(i, i + 100));
        }
        
        await Promise.all(partitionedPurgelist.map(messages => channel.bulkDelete(messages)));
        
        return purgeAmount;
    }
```

I'm pretty sure the only line that matters is the `fetch()` call. When called in my program, the API is giving me 50 messages. Is that intentional? I know there is an option for `limit`, but that only goes up to 100. If there is any workarounds to this, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Discord API has a hard limit of 100 messages per `GET` request. Unfortunately, this is a hard limit you can't bypass, and is intentional on Discord's part.

Furthermore, fetching the entirety of a text channel is probably a bad idea, especially with larger servers which could have 100k+ messages per channel.

A "sort-of" workaround is to use the `before` param in `FetchMessageOptions` plus a loop to continue fetching messages. See below for an example:

```js
const messages = [];
const messagesToFetch = 1000

while(messages.length < messagesToFetch) {
  // Handle first run
  if(!messages.length) {
    const msg = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 })
    messages.push(msg)
    continue;
  }
  
  // Fetch messages before the oldest message in the array
  messages.push(await channel.messages.fetch({  limit: 100, before: messages[0].id  }))
}
```

Comment: what you are doing here is not working properly. First of all, "msg" will be a collection, consisting of 100 arrays, which is then pushed as one element to the "messages" array. Second of all: the "push" method adds elements to the end of the array. Assuming your "messages" array would have received 100 elements during the first iteration, you'd be fetching the excact same collection from the second iteration on.